# bpy ray_cast doesn't find intersection from camera position to object position

Tags: python, scripting

I am currently trying to discover if any background object is in front of my foreground object (obj.name = 'Mhx2test') with blenderpython. To do this, I use the ray_cast method. So what I do is sending a ray from the camera directed to the foreground model what should return a position I can compare with the position of the foreground model to determine if the first intersection was with the foreground model or any other background model. I built a very basic scene with a Cube being between the camera and the foreground object:

[image: My scene's camera view where the foreground model is hidden behind the blue cube]

So the camera view shows that blue cube in front ob the foreground model. Sending a ray towards the foreground model should thus return the nearest intersection point with the cube. However when I run the following code it doesn't discover any intersection, i.e. the result is 'False'.

```
def detect_nearest_intersection():
    scene = bpy.context.scene
    me_tmp = bpy.data.meshes.new(name="~temp~")
    obj_tmp = bpy.data.objects.new(name=me_tmp.name, object_data=me_tmp)
    scene.objects.link(obj_tmp)
    scene.update()
    ray_cast = obj_tmp.ray_cast
    camera = bpy.context.scene.camera
    mod = bpy.data.objects['Mhx2test']
    direction = mod.location - camera.location;
    direction.normalize()
    result, location, normal, index = ray_cast(camera.location,direction)
    print("Raycast from %s to %s" % (camera.location, mod.location))
    print("Result: %s, location: %s, normal: %s, index: %s" % (result,location,normal,index))
```

Here is the output of the result:

```
Result: False, location: <Vector (0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000)>, normal: <Vector (0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000)>, index: -1
```

The ray_cast documentation from [here](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Object.html):

> ray_cast(origin, direction, distance=1.70141e+38) Cast a ray onto in
>   object space Parameters:   distance (float in [0, inf], (optional)) –
>   Maximum distance Return (result, location, normal, index): result,
>   boolean location, The hit location of this ray cast, float array of 3
>   items in [-inf, inf] normal, The face normal at the ray cast hit
>   location, float array of 3 items in [-inf, inf] index, The face index,
>   -1 when original data isn’t available, int in [-inf, inf]

I am using blender v2.78 (former versions implemented the ray_cast as ray_cast(start,end), v2.78 seems to use ray_cast(start,direction))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transforming the world coordinates to local coordinates fixed it.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem and this answer is very vague. I didn't downvote your answer but some elaboration would make it much more useful for people struggling with the same problem.